# Lando: exec error with environment variables

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables, lando

I'm using [Lando](https://lando.dev) (v3.0.0-rc.21 on Windows 10 Enterprise) and trying to set up an environment variable on container creation in my `.lando.yml`:

```
services:
  appserver:
    type: ruby # the same for php, but didn't tested other types
  run:
    - export SOMENAME=somevalue

tooling:
  test:
    cmd: export SOMENAME=somevalue
    service: appserver
```

It looks like the command is not recognized while Lando starts since it throws:
`OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"export\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

The very same error occurs on `lando ssh -c "export SOMENAME=somevalue"` or adding it as a command into tooling section in `.lando.yml` (see above) and then running `lando test`.

**However**, running the same command from `lando ssh` after lando has started works as it should:

```
lando ssh
www-data@81bd623b9c3a:/app$ export SOMENAME=somevalue
www-data@81bd623b9c3a:/app$ printenv SOMENAME
somevalue
www-data@81bd623b9c3a:/app$
```

Is this a Lando bug? Or some (which?) shell commands should be called somehow different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use this `env_file` in lando yaml:

```
env_file:
  - defaults.env
```

in `defaults.env`:

```
SOMENAME=somevalue
```

see [this](https://docs.lando.dev/config/env.html#environment-files)

Comment: Thanks! This does not resolves the issue, but could be a workaround indeed.

Comment: Setting overrides in lando.yml also works fine as a workaround: https://docs.lando.dev/config/services.html#overrides

Comment: you will not find a solution using `export SOMENAME=somevalue` since that will work only in the current session you need to define the variable using one of the two methods mentioned above

Comment: Well, it does not work even for a current session... But setting environmental variables on the fly may be useful in tooling section to run the same scripts with different environment settings. Take for example a command like  `WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0 ./bin/webpack-dev-server`. And it looks strange why it works via SSH but does not from a Lando config.

Answer (score 1):

Just to pull this from the comments. Ended up with a workaround with *Lando overrides* like this:

```
services:
  appserver:
    type: ruby # or other type
    overrides:
      environment:
        SOMENAME: somevalue
```

Documentation: https://docs.lando.dev/config/services.html#overrides

Another workaround — as @LinPy suggests in his answer — is to use external `env_file`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the variable available in the CLI you can do this:

```js
events:
  post-start:
    - appserver: "export PHP_IDE_CONFIG=\"serverName=appserver\""
```

Run `lando restart -y && lando ssh` then check the value via `printenv | grep PHP_IDE_CONFIG`